# How to ignore comma and print out elements using Arraylist<String>?

Tags: java, validation, arraylist, input

I want to check if the input will contain `"Cheese Sandwich", "Corn Sandwich"` and `"Mix Veg Sandwich"`. The conditions are:

> 1. if input entered matches the stored elements in `Arraylist<String>`, print out elements.
> 2. if input doesn't match the stored elements in `Arraylist`, print `Incorrect Input`.
> 3. if the input can contain a long string separated by comma, it has to ignore the comma and print out the strings between the comma.

In my program, I created a list and stored those three strings in it, then looped them and checked if the input matches the stored elements. The issue is when the input is given in the form of a string and then add these elements with comma it gives me nothing or incorrect input. How do I ignore the comma and split the string to be printed as following.

**Example:**

```
String Input = "Cheese Sandwich, Corn Sandwich, Mix Veg Sandwich";
```

**Expected Output**

```
cheese sandwich
corn sandwich 
mix veg sandwich
```

**My Program**

```
static void storeElements(String input) {

    List<String> sandwiches = new ArrayList<>();
    sandwiches.add("corn sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("mix veg sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("cheese sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("mix veg sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("cheese sandwich");
   

    boolean a = sandwiches.contains(input);
    boolean b = input.contains(",");

    List<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(input.split(",")));
```

I do not know how to make this `ArrayList` check the comma
in the string input and then validate if the input matches one of the elements in the stored `ArrayList` sandwiches.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (b) {
                for (String c : sandwiches) {
                    if (a) {
                        System.out.println(c);
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect Input");
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean: "print the String into arraylist"? why would you check if(a) if you need to check if the list contains c?

Comment: I have another question: What does *if input exist in element..* mean?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I thinki he means: if the element is in the list, print the element.

Comment: @Stultuske then he/she has to clarify, whether this can be an empty string element.

Comment: Also, if you're dealing with "input", exclusively, what does this ArrayList have to do in this context? please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66277494/edit) your question, make it clearer and define the exact problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Waelalmerri I think I know the issues you've been having. Can you check my answer to see if it answers your questions about why your code didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your initial code, with some comments

```
   static void storeElements(String input) {
            List<String> sandwiches = new ArrayList<>();
            sandwiches.add("corn sandwich");
            sandwiches.add("mix veg sandwich");
            sandwiches.add("cheese sandwich");
            sandwiches.add("mix veg sandwich");
            sandwiches.add("cheese sandwich");               
    
            boolean a = sandwiches.contains(input); // boolean a is set here, and it is never changed. So, if you enter "cheese sandwich, mix veg sandwich" a will never become true.
            boolean b = input.contains(",");
    
            List<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(input.split(",")));
    
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                if (b) {
                        for (String c : sandwiches) { // You shouldn't be iterating over sandwiches, but over list
                            if (a) { // a is not dependent on your c. this test should only be done if b is false. here, you need to check if an element of list is in sandwiches
                                System.out.println(c);
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println("Incorrect Input");
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

The altered code

```
static void storeElements(String input) {
    List<String> sandwiches = new ArrayList<>();
    sandwiches.add("corn sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("mix veg sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("cheese sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("mix veg sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("cheese sandwich");

    boolean a = sandwiches.contains(input);
    boolean b = input.contains(",");

    List<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(input.split(", ")));


        if (b) {
            for (String c : list) {
                System.out.println(sandwiches.contains(c) ? c : "Incorrect Input");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(a ? input : "Incorrect Input"); // here it makes sense to check if a is true
        }
}
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
static void storeElements(String input) {
    List<String> sandwiches = new ArrayList<>();
    sandwiches.add("corn sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("mix veg sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("cheese sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("mix veg sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("cheese sandwich");

    List<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(input.split(", ")));
    for (String c : list) {
      System.out.println(sandwiches.contains(c) ? c : "Incorrect Input");
    }
}
```

In my original answer, I had split(","), which I copied from the original, but I overlooked this:

if you execute split(",") on "cheese sandwich, corn sandwich", you get "cheese sandwich" and " corn sandwich". The first will be found, the second won't, since " corn" is not the same as "corn", the space does make a difference.

EDIT: only print Incorrect Input if none matched.

```
static void storeElements(String input) {
    List<String> sandwiches = new ArrayList<>();
    sandwiches.add("corn sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("mix veg sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("cheese sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("mix veg sandwich");
    sandwiches.add("cheese sandwich"); // this line is not relevant, the value is already in sandwiches

    List<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(input.split(", ")));
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (String c : list) {
      if ( sandwiches.contains(c)) {
          result.add(c); // only add the String if it is found in the original list
      } else {
              result.clear();
              break;
      }
    }

    if ( result.isEmpty()) {
        // this will only happen if no elements have been added to the result list
        System.out.println("Incorrect input");
    } else {
        for ( String found : result ) {
            System.out.println(found);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works when the input equals to on of the element but when the string is "Cheese Sandwich, Corn Sandwich, Mix Veg Sandwich" the output is mixed with "Incorrect Input"

Comment: @Waelalmerri that's because "Cheese Sandwich" and "cheese sandwich" are not the same. equals, which is used by the contains method, is case sensitive

Comment: i tried with lowercase as well, same result

Comment: @Waelalmerri I checked (wrote the code pretty fast) and found the issue, I'll edit my answer with a better solution

Comment: thanks it works, one issue though. it goes looping over each word and print it out even with "Incorrect Input". the function has to printout "incorrect input" only if any one wrong input that doesnt match the list is given.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, can you clarify that more? You mean Incorrect input should only be printed if none of the values were in the list?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if only value is wrong like if i add "milk" in the string "Cheese Sandwich, Corn Sandwich, Mix Veg Sandwich, milk" the ouput should be only "Incorrect input"

Comment: then what you can do is not print during the loop, but store the information in a way that later on you can verify whether or not input has been found. I'll update with an example

Comment: @Waelalmerri does this do what you need it to do? If so, can you mark the question as solved?

Comment: actually its not, am not looking if the list is empty or not, what am looking at is that the list would not contain any other element that the three mentioned strings. So if I add "milk" to the list while all three strings exist it should give me incorrect input for all. it has it accept the three strings only.

Comment: wait, so if you input "cheese sandwich, cheese sandwich, milk" it should return return Invalid Input three times?

Comment: let say the correct list is "cheese sandwich, corn sandwich, veg mix sandwich", if I add one more item like "milk" example "cheese sandwich, corn sandwich, veg mix sandwich, milk" then only one output shows "incorrect Input" unrepeated

Comment: In order to get that, there is only a small change you need to do. In your for loop, where you check whether or not the input is within the original list, add an else block. if it's not found, clear the contents of result, and break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things considerably by realizing that you only have one kind of input to consider: a comma-separated list of items. `"Cheese Sandwich, Corn Sandwich, Mix Veg Sandwich"` is quite obviously a comma-separated list, with three items.  `"Cheese Sandwich"`, somewhat less obviously, is _also, a comma-separated list, with just one item.

So just handle *all* inputs as comma-separated lists and everything becomes much less complicated:

```
static void storeElements(String input) {

        List<String> sandwiches = new ArrayList<>();
        sandwiches.add("corn sandwich");
        sandwiches.add("mix veg sandwich");
        sandwiches.add("cheese sandwich");
        sandwiches.add("mix veg sandwich");
        sandwiches.add("cheese sandwich");
       
        List<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(input.split("\\s*,\\s*")));

        for (String item : list) {
            item = item.toLowerCase();
            if (sandwiches.contains(item) {
                System.out.println("Yes, we have " + item);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect input");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: In your codes, it only check the first word and return Incorrect Input for the rest two

Comment: I revised the code slightly, to handle spaces before or after commas, and also uppercase vs. lowercase issues.

Comment: thanks it works, one issue though. it goes looping over each word and print it out even with "Incorrect Input". the function has to printout "incorrect input" only if any one wrong input that doesnt match the list is given.